# Creating a "since last refresh" KPI?

Tags: powerbi

I have a PowerBI that pulls from an excel spreadsheet a current inventory of statuses of a system, lets make it easy and say I have a single measure that reads "40% complete".

If I refresh the PowerBI dataset and it now says "60%", is there any way to have a KPI automatically show +20%? Every example I've found requires you to have another dataset that keeps the historical data, and that's not really an option in this situation. Is there any way to calculate it or store it within the PowerBI query itself?

Comment: You can look into appending the data instead of replacing it, maybe add a timestamp field. This way you have all the necessary details in the same dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Power BI is not designed to store historical data. This is what a database is for.

In order to calculate that 20% difference, you need to store historical data somewhere but Power BI's purpose is to connect to sources and load data and then visualize it, not to act as a data repository.